# "vertical-align:middle" does not work when apply the container element "float"

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

The following code works well:

```
<div id="container">
   <p>test</p>
</div>

#container{height:500px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
```

but when the `container`element has the css property:`float:left`

it cannot work!!

I just want vertical-middle while floating

Comment: What good does knowing *why* it doesn't work?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are right! what i need is how-to rather than why.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set `line-height` in this case:

`line-height:500px`

Comment: but multiple lines content,it doesnot work.

Comment: [http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)